# How to check if an item is equal to any item in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

For instance, if I had an `int[5] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

and an `int check = 5`

Is there an easy way to check `if (check == any item in array)` then do something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use the `Contains` LINQ method.  You'll need to add `using System.Linq` to access the method.

```
if(array.Contains(5))
{
    //TODO do stuff
}
```

Comment: @IvarBonsaksen Agreed, but it's not an easy problem to solve.

Comment: No, unfortunately. I can see the problem has been discussed many times on meta, but as far as I can see, no one has come up with a good solution yet.

Comment: @IvarBonsaksen Well, the reputation cap is there to help mitigate the issue, but it can only help to a point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) method. This method returns `true` if the source sequence contains an element that has the specified value; otherwise, `false`.

> Determines whether a sequence contains a specified element by using
>   the default equality comparer.

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
if(array.Contains(5))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Array has an element called 5");
}
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://ideone.com/9Br8Mm)**.

Dont forget to add **[`System.Linq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145016.aspx)** namespace.

***NOTE***: Positive side of `Contains()` method, the enumeration is terminated as soon as a matching element is found. If you search the element like;

```
foreach(var i in array)
{
  if(i == 5)
  ///
}
```

You have to enumerate all elements in array. I think this is biggest benefit of this method in this situation.

Comment: Your additional note doesn't make much sense. All you need to do is add the `break` keyword when you match your element and leave the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Joshua Of course you can use `break` at this point. But OP asked **easy way**, so `Contains()` method easier than checking every element in array. Because second one is needed, as you say, break statement for getting same result with `Contains()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (array.Contains(check))
{
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

```
array.Contains(check)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 };
int check = 5;

int r = Array.Find<int>(array, (arr => arr == check));
if (r != 0)
{
    // then do something.
}
```

Comment: But I like to use the LINQ syntax to do this work. Because if we know the LINQ we can use the same knowledge to query with various different types of source.